# Maximality of an order.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I am stuck and I don't know how should I show that

$$\mathcal{O}=\{x+yi+zj+wk \ | \Big(x, y, z, w \in \mathbb{Z}\Big) \ or \ \Big(x, y, z, w \in (\dfrac{1}{2}+\mathbb{Z})\Big) \}$$

that $\mathcal{O}$ is a maximal order in
$\mathbb{H_Q}=\mathbb{Q}\oplus\mathbb{Q}i\oplus\mathbb{Q}j\oplus\mathbb{Q}k$, where $i^2=j^2=k^2=-1=ijk$.

---

My attempt:

I can show that it is an order.
Let $B$ be another order containing $\mathcal O$,
and let $m:=[B:\mathcal{O}]$.
Then we have $mB \subseteq \mathcal{O} \subseteq B$. But I can not go further.